# Conditional probability, Bernouilli's trial alternative method..

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

So I got this question on an practice test, and my first thought was to use Bernouilli's trial to solve for the answer. My question is how to possibly solve it without Bernouilli's trial, in a manner simply using conditional probabilities. I don't really know how to approach it in that case, however I figure it has to be extremely simple.

Customers at a store independently decide whether to pay by credit card or with cash. Suppose the probability is 70% that a customer pays by card. Find the probability that 3 out of 5 customers pay by card.

Comment: You don't need to use conditional probabilities, because every customer pays by card with probability 0.7, *regardless* of what the other customers are doing.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, it was under the "conditional probabilities" section of questions which is what was misleading me.

Comment: That's probably because you need to understand what the "independently" in the question meant, and that comes under the topic of conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

$p = 0.7$, and $q = 1 - p = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3$. Thus:

$P(x = 3) = \binom{5}{3}(0.7)^3\cdot (0.3)^2 = 0.3087 \approx 0.3$